# php regular expression preg_match

Tags: php, expression, match

notice the change in $pattern

```
$subject = '<table width="750"  style="padding-left:150px;"><tr><td width="108"class="fieldname">First Name:</td><td width="381" class="fieldname">';

    $pattern = '/(table)/';
    $matches = array();
    echo preg_match( $pattern, $subject, $matches)."<br/>";
    echo $matches[0]."<br/>";
```

gives me output
 
1
table

AND prefixing table by < in $pattern gives me output
 
1

WHY ?? shouldn't i get < table as ouput ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get it, but you don't see it(it's HTML-markup and the browser tries to render a table).

Use

```
 echo htmlentities($matches[0])."<br/>";
```

...to inspect the matches.

Answer (score 0):

when you echo the result of preg_match, you will get a boolean, so '1', is what one would expect.  $matches[1] and $matches[0] will both give you 'table', so that is what one would expect.  Tell us what you want to match, and we can help.

a preg_match &modified variable in the last argument will give you:
 - [0] the total match
 - [1] the match between parentheses

Although the answer above is correct, <(space)table should give you a boolean FALSE.  If the above answerer is correct in his assumption that no space was intended, then his answer is correct, you are viewing the browser output and not the source.

Comment: I think he means changing the pattern to `'/(<table)/'`.

Comment: Ya the space wasn't intended and the guy above is right. Thank you too...!!